The liquidity of bank's assets and bank's systemic risk
I would have the following question. May the liquidity of a bank's assets be non-linearly related to the bank's systemic risk? More specifically, more liquidity can increase systemic risk during stable times but reduces it during normal times or this relationship should be, in your view, the same across both? Thank you in advance for your time.
